# How to protect video course materials provided to students

Tags: ownership

Apologies if this isn't the right part of Stack Exchange, this seems the right place though.

I'm helping a music teacher friend who lives on private tuition. They want to provide short videos that students can learn with between face-toface lessons but doesn't want those videos getting passed on in the wider world.    They aren't looking for a get-rich-quick scheme, the teacher wants to teach one-to-one students.

We've looked at You Tube and Vimeo so far. In the student context I understand this means:

- Vimeo simply uses password access. i.e. if one student passes on the
  password then there is no protection.
- You tube has a feature that requires a student to log in with their own gmail account which has been pre-authorised by the teacher. This seems ideal except that it seems not to work. The user interface accepts one e-mail address and then refuses to add or delete any users.

**Question:** Are there any other online tools that provide protection to teachers distributing course materials?

**Context #1**  I don't think they are that bothered about people thousands of miles away getting the benefit. Its more just where it might make the difference between a recommendation from a current student to a potential new one (i.e. very positive) instead becoming "here, use all these videos for free" (i.e. a direct loss of income).

**Context #2**  Clearly we realise there is no protection from someone using you-tube downloader or something like that other than putting the teachers emblem in the corner of the video.

Comment: If the videos are just complimentary to the lessons, where is the potential harm? Wouldn´t it be better to just release them publicly once you´ve gone to the effort of creating them - getting the publicity as advertising effect for the real product (the lessons)?

Comment: @Daniel this is a good point and we've thought of it though its hard to call as a judgement if its an all or nothing decision. The market is for face to face lessons with local students. Its an unusual musical instrument though there certainly is a market. The ideal would be to release some videos publicly and hold back some others and so this question is about how to manage the latter.

Comment: You still have the legality on your side to deter anyone to make a profit from your work. Other than that, the DRM-Topic is complicated and even major companies are struggling with it. Sorry I have no good answer other than this.

Comment: Anyone care to offer a reason for the -2 received this week?

Answer (score 1):

One methodology you could use is a page with an expiring link.
You would embed the video into a webpage that once viewed will expire. You would need some coding knowledge to do so but the security will be protected that way.